# On cloud9, how do you push one config for nodester, another to github

Tags: git, github, cloud9-ide, nodester

Okay, so wanting to start a little oss project via c9.  I'd like to publish one config (private to nodester, containing for example mongolab credentials).  I would rather not have this information in the example config that goes to github... how do others handle this?

Also, is this possible on a free c9 account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd like to suggest you to read this [article](https://github.com/nodester/nodester/wiki/How-to-deploy-to-Nodester-from-Cloud9-IDE) which tell you how to deploy from c9. In addition you can add environmental variables via our [API explorer](http://nodester.com/api#explorer) or via curl:

`curl -X PUT -u "testuser:123" -d "appname=a&key=color&value=blue" http://api.nodester.com/env`

So for example you want the MONGO_URL, you can do this:

(this is a one line command)

`$ curl -XPUT -u "username:password" -d "appname=myappname&key=MONGO_URL&value=http://link.to/mongo/db" http://api.nodester.com/env`

And then in your app:

`var mongo = require('mongodriver');`

`var db = mongo.connect(MONGO_URL);`

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

From within cloud9 I'd suggest using the command line arguments (in the run panel) to set sensitive config data. These are not visible to the outside world unless you grant someone write access.

You can depend on the presence of the environment variable `C9_PROJECT` to determine that you are in Cloud9.

Comment: I'm actually wanting to publish to github... and.. git push to nodester...  Where this fails, is I don't want the nodester settings to be in the github repo.. apparently env vars are the way to go.